# highcharts on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

I have two charts which are produced through a xml data. but it doesn't work on IE9.

Here the code:

```
var chart;var chartB;
jQuery(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            marginTop: 160

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Wochen\u00FCbersicht',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Minuten'

            },

        },
```

the series are filled from xml

```
        series: []
    };`load Data from xml file`
    // Load the data from the XML file 
        $.get('Woche.xml', function(xml) {

            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);

            // push categories
            $xml.find('categories Monat').each(function(i, category) {
                options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
            });

            // push series
            $xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {
                var seriesOptions = {
                    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                    data: []
                };

                // push data points
                $(series).find('data Minuten').each(function(i, Minuten) {
                    seriesOptions.data.push(
                        parseInt($(Minuten).text())
                    );
                });

                // add it to the options
                options.series.push(seriesOptions);
```

set color

```
                Highcharts.setOptions({ colors: ['#faebd7', '#00ffff ', '#000000', '#0000ff', '#8a2be2', '#7fff00', '#00008b', '#008000', '#ff1493', '#800000', '#ffa500', '#006400', '#ffff00', '#008080', '#ff0000', '#000080', '#bdb76b', '#20b2aa', '#ffd700', '#00ffff',] });
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

here begins the second chart

```
    var options2 = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containerB',
            type: 'column',

        },

        title: {
            text: 'Monats\u00FCbersicht',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Minuten'
            },
        },
        series: []
    };
    // Load the data from the XML file 

        $.get('Monat.xml', function(xml) {

            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);

            // push categories
            $xml.find('categories Monat').each(function(i, category) {
                options2.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
            });

            // push series
            $xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {
                var seriesOptions = {
                    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                    data: []
                };

                // push data points
                $(series).find('data Minuten').each(function(i, Minuten) {
                    seriesOptions.data.push(
                        parseInt($(Minuten).text())
                    );
                });

                // add it to the options
                options2.series.push(seriesOptions);
                Highcharts.setOptions({ colors: ['#faebd7', '#00ffff ', '#000000', '#0000ff', '#8a2be2', '#7fff00', '#00008b', '#008000', '#ff1493', '#800000', '#ffa500', '#006400', '#ffff00', '#008080', '#ff0000', '#000080', '#bdb76b', '#20b2aa', '#ffd700', '#00ffff',] });
            });
            var chartB = new Highcharts.Chart(options2);
        });

     });
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the JSON options for each chart - you've a trailing comma after yAxis title, which isn't supported with IE.